# Drupal 7 Adding PHP to View FIlter

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, view

I can't seem to find the answer, and im sure its something simple...

I need to add a small block of PHP code to a view filter.

I am using the same PHP code elsewhere on the site to load a certain users profile information from a database, not the logged in user, but a user they have clicked on elsewhere on the site.

Possibly I am doing this wrong all together, if so please advise a better way as well!

thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the <a href="http://drupal.org/project/views_php">Views PHP</a> module? FYI, there is a Drupal site that might be more helpful (http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Are you creating your own view filter in a custom module or are you simply wanting to add custom PHP to a view via the Views UI?

Comment: just thinking - maybe create contextual filter with default value as php code and place code there?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create custom filtering in views. [Here is the link](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-filters-views)